# Converting Quoted string to integer?

Tags: sql-server, file, ssis, flat

I have an SSIS project where Flat File Source reads CSV file. It contains a field Order Item Id that is formatted as a string like "347262171", surrounded by quotes. I want to convert that to numeric value so I can use it as an index but everything I try gives me result:

> Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Order Item ID" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

What would be the easiest workaround for this?

Comment: Please don't convert ID numbers to an actual number type. Note that you will never perform arithmatic on an ID number. It will only lead to problems with leading zeroes for example.

Comment: Also, check the metadata on the column that you're using for the new number; check if it is big enough for the 'numbers'. An ID of `347262171` as in your example is a small string, but a pretty big number. Another point against 'int'-ID fields.

Comment: BTW, are the quotes in the actual source file, or are they added by the Flat File Connection? You can disable the latter, but I don't know if this would interfere with other parts of the data flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Derived Column Transformation  (DCT) to the data flow where you add an expression that removes quotes from the value:

```
REPLACE( [ID FIELD], "\"", "" )
```

where `ID FIELD` is the column with the ID value in your data. Add this column as a new NVARCHAR column to your data flow (ie `STRIPPED_ID_FIELD`).

Then, add a second DCT, where you cast this value to number `(DB_NUMERIC(10,0))[STRIPPED_ID_FIELD]`, and name it `NUM_ID_FIELD`.

The reason I'd to this in a second, separate DCT, is that you can add an error output to this second one, and redirect that to a Recordset Destination. Then add a Data Viewer to the error output to see what sort of records are wrong. For instance, ID fields that have a letter that you're not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the double quotes in a Flat file connection by specifying Text Qualifier =" ,if you are using flat file .

[Image description of where to insert Qualifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnr63.jpg)